# Get javascript binding string value

Tags: javascript

I have a simple function that traverses up the DOM to get to a span element:

```
function getAttachmentControlBinding(theNode) {
  //Find the <SPAN> tag that has the binding to the attachment control
  //The attachment control is needed to be able to determine from which view
  do {
    //Navigate up to the parent node
    theNode = theNode.parentNode;
  //Should run into a <SPAN> tag, but if not we need to get out of the loop
  } while (theNode.nodeName !== "SPAN" && theNode.nodeName !== '');

  //Get the value of the binding attribute from the <SPAN> tag
  return theNode.getAttribute("binding");
}
```

In the JS console, if I look at `theNode`, I get this:

`<span id="svattachmentcontainer_0_1" binding="my:wsAttachmentCreditApplication"`

The binding here is what I want the function to return; however I keeping getting an error of `illegal return statement` if I try to evaluate in the console.  If I evaluate `theNode.getAttribute("binding")` in the console, I get what I want (`my:wsAttachmentCreditApplication`), but letting the code run jumps to a completely different section of code that would normally run if this function return was successful.

How can I return this value with this function?

Comment: Could you reproduce it in a JSFiddle? It works fine for me when I try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine

```js
function getAttachmentControlBinding(theNode) {
  //Find the <SPAN> tag that has the binding to the attachment control
  //The attachment control is needed to be able to determine from which view
  do {
    //Navigate up to the parent node
    theNode = theNode.parentNode;
  //Should run into a <SPAN> tag, but if not we need to get out of the loop
  } while (theNode.nodeName !== "SPAN" && theNode.nodeName !== '');

  //Get the value of the binding attribute from the <SPAN> tag
  return theNode.getAttribute("binding");
}


var binding = getAttachmentControlBinding(document.querySelector('.nesteddiv2'));

document.querySelector('.js-result').innerHTML = 'Binding found: ' + binding;
```

```html
<span id="svattachmentcontainer_0_1" binding="my:wsAttachmentCreditApplication">
    <div class="nesteddiv1">
        <div class="nesteddiv2"></div>
    </div>
</span>

<div class="js-result">aa</div>
```

Comment: Yes I see that...why would I be getting the error that I'm getting?

Comment: @stphnlwlsh we can't help you with that without having a demo to look at

Comment: The demo you put together is exactly what I'm experiencing.  This js is run from within another library, and I have a feeling it's erring out somewhere in there.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @stphnlwlsh my only guess is that you are trying to use "return" outside of a function - I'm not sure why else you would be getting Illegal return statement